# parsing json file store in Map

Tags: json, bash

I have a json file like this and I want to save both "id" and "tenantId" in some map as key/value pair to process further. Is there a way I can parse my JSON to do that?

```
{
    "type": "nodesRepresentation",
    "paging": {
        "cursorAfter": "NjA3YmUyMjA4ZjdkMTMwMDAxMDc1MDlk",
        "limit": 50,
        "pageSize": 2,
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "/api/node/nodes%3Fafter=NjA3YmUyMjA4ZjdkMTMwMDAxMDc1MDlk&limit=50",
                "rel": "next"
            }
        ]
    },
    "pageSize": 2,
    "values": [
        {
            
            "id": "a423a565-8ae3-4d99-9c8a-92b8af843228",
            
            "tenantId": "4d010b5a-a9ab-4e7d-b989-6a05245105ed"
            
               
            
        },
        {
            
            "id": "e350ffaa-d62e-4cfc-9a3b-ae4624d35dc0",
            "tenantId": "8725905d-90c4-4728-a94a-47c0d57f8251"
           
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq). Since you haven’t specified precisely the result you want, I’d suggest starting with

```
jq ‘.values[]' myfile.json
```